# Hyperledger Fabric - Commercial Paper tutorial - chaincode instantiate error

Tags: docker, npm, hyperledger-fabric

I have been following the Commercial Paper tutorial from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/tutorial/commercial_paper.html

When I instantiate the chaincode by running the following command

```
docker exec cliMagnetoCorp peer chaincode instantiate -n papercontract -v 0 -l node -c '{"Args":["org.papernet.commercialpaper:instantiate"]}' -C mychannel -P "AND ('Org1MSP.member')"
```

I get the following error after a few minutes

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting chaincode papercontract:0 for transaction
```

I have been digging down a bit and it seem the "dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0" is failing

dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0 logs show the following:

```
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! path /usr/local/src/package.json
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! code ENOENT
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! errno -2
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! syscall open
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/src/package.json'
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! enoent 
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-02-08T11_51_20_601Z-debug.log
```

Have been stuck at it for two days, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: The steps before this run smoothly as expected.
Also the first network simulation (./byfn.sh up) runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need the package.json inside the directory of the chaincode. For example, the chaincode directory name is: ./Chaincode , and inside should be chaincode.js and package.json.
In the package.json, on start, in script  you should put "node chaincode.js". That because the peer use npm start to execute the chaincode.